# Image conversion problem with image_view video_recorder

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to directly record a video from an image topic using video_recorder from image_view.
I am testing it with my laptop camera running

```
roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch
```

When I launch the recording with

```
rosrun image_view video_recorder image:="/usb_cam/image_raw" _filename:="/home/user/video.avi"
```

I get the following error "Unable to convert rgb8 image to bgr8".
I have also tryed using

```
rosrun image_view video_recorder image:="/usb_cam/image_raw" _filename:="/home/user/video.avi" _encoding:="rgb8"
```

but this produces "Unable to convert rgb8 image to rgb8".

The exact same happens for images published by the V-REP simulator (which is what I actually need to record in the end).

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Riccardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228085/image-conversion-problem-with-image_view-video_recorder/) by [rick187](https://answers.ros.org/users/4440/rick187/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ASeyfi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26457/aseyfi/) on 2016-04-01**:
I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

**Comment by [rick187](https://answers.ros.org/users/4440/rick187/) on 2016-04-01**:
No, I am afraid I didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I just solved this issue, try to set the parameter "`<param name="max_depth_range" value="0" />"enter code here` . The default value is 5 and this seems to mess something up. That problem disappeared for me but I still cannot open the output video by the way.

Andrea

---

Originally posted by [andrea-nisti](https://answers.ros.org/users/26506/andrea-nisti/) with karma: 26 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently there is a solution [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/187)

---

Originally posted by [ASeyfi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26457/aseyfi/) with karma: 21 on 2016-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have accepted the last answer because it is more complete, but the one from ASeyfi points in the right direction too. I don't know the rules in these cases.

Anyway I finally solved with this command:

rosrun image_view video_recorder image:="/usb_cam/image_raw" _filename:="/tmp/video.avi" _max_depth_range:="0" _fps:="30" _codec:="I420"

I can open the file in VLC and it works perfectly. The last option (the codec) can be removed and the video still plays fine (but it is compressed in this case).

Thank you all.

Riccardo

---

Originally posted by [rick187](https://answers.ros.org/users/4440/rick187/) with karma: 63 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2